# How to make a custom multi-part field for an integer in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to have a field for a span of time in a rails form, with 3 input fields, for hours, minutes, and seconds, and store all of this as in integer (in seconds) in the DB. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done automatically, but some simple controller code would work.

```
params[:timespan] = (params.delete(:hours).to_i * 3600) + 
                    (params.delete(:minutes).to_i * 60) +
                    params.delete(:seconds).to_i
```

Comment: so this code when go in the update, new, and create methods? I'm still kinda new to rails and how all this works.

Comment: @GSto it would go in the `create` and `update` actions, and you'll probably want some logic to make sure you want to replace the timespan value.